# i want to make select from datastore ,but its not work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

i was tried to make select statement ,but its not work.
its return null.
i use jpql in my eclipse .

```
public static List<Follow> getFollows() {
    List<Follow> follow = null;
    EMFService emf = new EMFService();
    EntityManager em = emf.getEmf().createEntityManager();
    try {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Follow");
        follow = q.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return follow;
}
```

Comment: When you put something into the empty catch block like a log statement, does it tell you you're doing something wrong maybe?

Comment: Never, never, _never_ have a totally empty `catch` block.  If your code throws an exception you'll never know what happened.

Comment: i was deleted try clause ,and invoke this function in another try clause this message was printed in catch////// javax.persistence.PersistenceException: FROM clause of query has class com.yassir.followup.Follow but no alias

Comment: after this i  make an alias to my query ,but the result also null.. java.lang.NullPointerException was printed in catch

Answer (score 0):

Since when has `SELECT * FROM Follow` been valid JPQL ?!!! Strongly suggest that you read a JPA tutorial rather than making it up as you go along.

```
SELECT f FROM Follow f
```